# Unable to query data from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase. Here's my code snippet

```
Future main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data').doc("rules");
    docRef.get().then(
          (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return MyHomePage(title: 'ARNET Helper',
            rules: data['ruleslist']);
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error getting document: $e"),
    );
    return Spinner(text: "Unable to retrieve data");
  }

}
```

Here's the corresponding Firebase database screenshot
[image]

I do have the google-services.json added to the android/app folder. But with the above snippet, lines from the "then" block don't seem to get hit and the spinner (i.e return Spinner(text: "Unable to retrieve data");) is always returned.

I do have these lines added to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I tried to debug it. But the breakpoint at line 46 is never hit. Instead the execution goes straight to line 52. What am I missing?
[image]

I've even tried using FutureBuilder as suggested by one of the commenters. I always get "Something went wrong.." spinner

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference data = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future:  data.doc('rules').get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Spinner(text: 'Something went wrong...');
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Spinner(text: 'Document does not exist...');
        }


        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data! as Map<String, dynamic>;

          return MyHomePage(title: 'ARNET Helper', rules: data['ruleslist'].entries.toList() as List<dynamic>);
        }

        return Spinner(text: 'Loading...');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the issue was but the config below worked.

pubspec.yaml

```
  firebase_core: ^1.24.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.5.0
```

FutureBuilder query

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference data = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future:  data.doc("rules").get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Spinner(text: 'Something went wrong...');
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Spinner(text: 'Document does not exist...');
        }


        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final data = snapshot.data!.get('ruleslist') ;

          return MyHomePage(title: 'ARNET Helper', rules: data);
        }

        return Spinner(text: 'Loading...');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `get()` is an asynchronous operation, and you can't return widgets asynchronously in `build`.

The simplest way to fix this is to use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data').doc("rules").get(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final data = asyncSnapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return MyHomePage(title: 'ARNET Helper', rules: data['ruleslist']);
      }
      else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}")
      } 
      else {
        return Text("Loading user data...")
      }    
    }    
  )
}
```

Comment: I've tried that too but no luck. I've updated my answer with the snipped of code for FutureBuilder.

Comment: At that stage we're looking at a completely different problem though. Did you print `snapshot.error` to see what the root cause is of this new problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the Firebase Instance?

```
await Firebase.initializeApp()
```

Comment: Yes, I have! I've updated the question with the code snippet for init.

Comment: try to initialize your app with flutter and see.